# How to show values defined in properties file?

Tags: jsp, properties, struts2, locale

I am trying to use locale in my application, I am able to retrieve the values from my properties files.

The problem is that I just want to show the messages but do not know how, I used

```jsp
    <s:url action="retrieveValues" var="myValues">
        <s:param name="request_locale">val</s:param>
    </s:url>


   <s:label key="mytext"/>
```

It works but I just need the value of mytext be shown as a single text.

Lets say value of mytext is Hello world when I use the above code it shows

```
     Hello world: Hello world
```

how can I change it to

```
     Hello World
```

So it does not show "Hello world:"

Comment: Just use appropriate tag for displaying messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a property like following in your property file

```
mytext=Hello World
```

you can use the following in the JSP

```
<s:text name="mytext"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but how about the following code?

```
 <s:property value="myText"/>
```

Comment: If you are not sure use comment section.